# is it possible that we have some intermediate dialing screen iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I am using this code phone calling from iPhone its calling directly to particular number.My question is it it possible to have some intermediate dialing screen so when i click on this button it leads to that screen and by clicking call button there i can make a call.Dial screen
 should be like the image.
[image]

```
-(IBAction)call{

    NSString *StrNumber = @"15553451290";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] ![enter image description here][1]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",StrNumber]]];

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No @zink. I think this facility is not available in ios. You can make a custom view like this and then from there you can put [[UIApplication sharedApplication] ![enter image description here][1]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",StrNumber]]];

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible. You will have to create a new screen with buttons of digits and calling button. You will have to get the phone number by those digits/buttons. And get the resultant full number and use it in the above function. The function will be called when user presses the call button.

Comment: thank you but i don't want to design this screen.My question is iphone is giving such functionality without designing it from our side?

Comment: @Saleh: i meant the same. She will have to create a custom view. But there is no such default facility available in ios unlike android

Answer (score 1):

U can do it by using icarousel.Just create temperorary view which have collection of buttons with numbers and call symbol.Then define a function to button that loads the view like pop in and pop out and u can do rest of the methods.